# This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that Play Integrity checks, and reCAPTCHA checks were unsuccessful

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I am getting this error when trying to verify phone number with OTP.

Here is what I did to solve this:

1. Added both release and debug SHA 1 key to Firebase App Settings
2. Added SHA 1 to Google API Key and made that unrestricted
3. Registered Play Integrity in FIrebase

Here are some of my code snippets:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
      androidProvider: AndroidProvider.playIntegrity,
      appleProvider: AppleProvider.debug
  );
  runApp(MainApp());
}

await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
    verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) {},
    verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {},
    codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) {},
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {},
  );
```

after that it tried to load captcha, but it returns from browser without verifying and show this error:

> [firebase_auth/missing-client-identifier] This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that Play Integrity checks, and reCAPTCHA checks were unsuccessful. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details

Here are the dependencies I used:

- firebase_core: ^2.8.0
- firebase_messaging: ^14.3.0
- firebase_crashlytics: ^3.0.17
- firebase_auth: ^4.3.0
- firebase_app_check: ^0.1.3

And Flutter Version is:
`Flutter version 3.7.12`

I am stuck in at app production. Can you please help me with this?